# Full copy of an instance of a dataclass with complex structure

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-dataclasses

I'd like to create a copy of an existing instance of a dataclass and modify it.

Suppose we have a dataclass and an instance of that dataclass:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field, InitVar, replace

@dataclass
class D:
    a: float = 10.                # Normal attribute with a default value
    b: InitVar[float] = 20.       # init-only attribute with a default value 
    c: float = field(init=False)  # an attribute that will be defined in __post_init__
    
    def __post_init__(self, b):
        self.c = self.a + b

d1 = D()
```

Let's define an instance and try to make a copy (I've tried solutions proposed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57962873/easiest-way-to-copy-all-fields-from-one-dataclass-instance-to-another)):

1. Using the `replace` method:

```
d2 = replace(d1, **{})
```

throws an error

```
InitVar 'b' must be specified with replace()
```

It seems to be a [reported bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue36470), but I am not sure if there is any progress on it.

2. By creating a new object from `__dict__` of an old object:

```
d2 = D(**d1.__dict__)
```

throws an error

```
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'c'
```

Do you have any suggestions on how to copy dataclass instance properly or "workaround" indicated issues?

---

#### Edit:

- Fixed the bug in the initial code (`self.b` in `__post_init__`)

<s>I've made this workaround which seems to be working (posted in answers). If someone can find drawbacks it will be very appreciated.</s>

Answer (score 13):

Just use the standard `copy` module:

```
d2 = copy.copy(d1)
```

If you want a deep copy, you can use `copy.deepcopy`.

---

Any approach based on calling the dataclass's constructor is doomed to failure. That includes `replace`, which delegates to the constructor. The problem is that InitVar values aren't stored anywhere, so there's no way to tell what values to pass for InitVars. (Particularly, `self.b` is *not* the provided value of `b` - it's the default value - so your `__post_init__` is broken.)

Comment: No, this could create a view instead of a copy. `copy.deepcopy(d1)` could work, however, if the complex logic of a dataclass requires its re-creation it could go wrong too.

Comment: @RomanZhuravlev: What? Dataclasses have no concept of a view. You can't create a view of a dataclass instance, because there's no such thing. It creates a *shallow* copy, but so did the original version of your answer, and the code in your question would have created a shallow copy of objects it actually worked for. If you want a deep copy, you can use `copy.deepcopy`, but you never indicated you wanted one.

Answer (score -1):

I've made this workaround which seems to be working. If someone can find drawbacks it will be very apreciated.

```
def copy_dataclass(D_class, d_obj, **kw):
    input = {**kw}
    for key, value in asdict(d_obj).items():
        # If the attribute is passed to __init__
        if d_obj.__dataclass_fields__[key].init:
            input[key] = copy.deepcopy(value)
        
    copy_d = D_class(**input)
    
    return copy_d
```

Which gives:

```
d2 = copy_dataclass(D, d1)

d1 == d2
# prints True

d1 is d2
# prints False
```

If we change a field in d2 it does not affect d1

```
d2.a = 50

print(f'd1 = {d1};\nd2 = {d2}')
# d1 = D(a=10.0, c=30.0);
# d2 = D(a=50, c=30.0)
```

---

#### Edit

- Added `copy.deepcopy(value)` for cases when dataclass attributes are mutable;
- `__dict__` rerplaced by `asdict()` method;
- <s>additional inputs can be provided to the method in order to replace the default values of `InitVars` attributes</s>
- <s>additional check can be added to verify that all `InitVars` were replaced (using `D.__dataclass_fields__`).</s>
  So, with these modifications we will get the `replace()` method...

Comment: Doesn't work. It only looks like it does because bugs in your `D` class and your `copy_dataclass` hide each other. You're misusing InitVars - your `__post_init__` completely ignores the provided value of `b`. If we [fix that bug](https://ideone.com/mA88O7), we see that your `copy_dataclass` fails to perform correct copies. Any approach that relies on calling the `D` constructor is doomed to failure, because InitVar values aren't actually stored anywhere, so we can't recover the values of InitVars.